OAuth Provider - Anonymous Authenticated User in authorize endpoint
We're trying to configure our Sitecore site as an OAuth SSO Provider. We configured the OWIN authorize endpoint, which redirects to the login screen.
When the user logs in and the user is redirected back to the authorize endpoint, we're supposed to check if the current user is authenticated, but Sitecore.Context.User still shows extranet\anonymous
We tested a web api that inherits the ServicesApiController and this shows the actual logged in user. But we just can't get the OWIN endpoints to access Sitecore's context user.
How can we achieve this?
This is the startup code:
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/oauth/authorize"),
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/oauth/token"),
    Provider = new OAuthServerProvider(),
    AuthorizationCodeProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(),
    AccessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProvider(),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
};

This is the authorize endpoint:
public class OAuthServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider {

    public override async Task AuthorizeEndpoint(OAuthAuthorizeEndpointContext context) {
        var user = Sitecore.Context.User; //shows as extranet\anonymous
    }
}



It turns out it's all about the FormsAuthentication cookie (.aspxauth). Since FormsAuthentication is disabled in Sitecore CD, this cookie doesn't get created.
I created it manually upon logging in and immediately I started seeing the logged in user when calling the API.
 var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                            1, // Ticket version
                            email, // Username associated with the ticket
                            DateTime.Now, // Date and time issued
                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // Expiration date and time
                            true, // Persistent
                            "/" // Cookie path
                        );
            var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
            {
                HttpOnly = true, // Ensures the cookie is accessible only by the server
                Secure = true,// FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL, // Ensures the cookie is sent only over HTTPS
                Expires = ticket.Expiration, // Sets the expiration time,
                Value = encryptedTicket,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
            };

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

